# Using a for-loop inside a while-loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

Go through a list and select all even numbers but stop when you have `15` numbers. To achieve this I thought of using the following:

```
nums = np.random.randint(1,100,50) # List of 50 numbers between 1 and 100

x = 0                              # variable to incriment
number = []                        # List to store even number
while x < 16:                       
  for num in nums:                 # Select each number in nums list
    if x%2 ==0:                    # Check if even
      number.append(num)           # Append even number to list
  x+=1                             # increment counter
```

but I get a list of length 400 and the counter (`x`) for 16.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While loops only check their condition at the end of each loop. But you are going through the entire list of nums before the end of the first loop.

Comment: For one, the `x += 1` is wrongly indented. You want to count the amount of numbers ***added*** so it should go at the same level as the `append` line. But `x` is not really necessary, just use `len(number)`

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Also, `if x%2==0:` is the wrong condition for your application.

Comment: @ basil why? how else would you test if a number is even ?

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks for the Python Tutor link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested for loop means the while loop condition doesn't get checked until the entire list has been looped over. I'd suggest get rid of the while loop and just use `break` to control the stopping condition.

```py
number = []
for num in nums:
    if num%2 == 0:
        number.append(num)
    if len(number) == 15:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks man. This works. I understand now that it was pointless to use a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for num in nums:
    if x%2 ==0:
      number.append(num)
```

This part of your code will always append the even numbers in the list `nums` to the list `number`, correct?

And now, you just repeat this 16 times over by wrapping it in the

```py
x = 0
while x < 16
    ...
    x += 1
```

Instead of this, you can just do

```
nums = np.random.randint(1,100,50) # List of 50 numbers between 1 and 100

x = 0
number = []
while len(number) < 15:                       
  for num in nums:
    if x%2 ==0:
      number.append(num)
    if len(number) < 15:
       break
```

or something similar

Comment: It will not.  It will only append every other number regardless of even/odd because the wrong test is being performed.

Comment: It's also redundant to check for breaks and *also* check the same condition in the while loop. There is never a time when the while loop would end, since if the condition was met, it would have already broken the loop.

Comment: Also the condition for `break`ing makes no sense. You will always `break` after the first number... Running your code I got a list of 64 numbers...

Comment: @Tomerikoo True actually, which means it will always be the same number added each time.

Comment: Oops my bad, I was wondering yesterday if the `break` would break the while loop or the for loop.